# How can one get notified /status if the Web API is done its long running job? I am using ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ASP.NET Core 6.0 Web API which does some integration work (time consuming process).

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<PushOutput>> TimeConsumingApi(PushInput payload)
{
    PushOutput result = new PushOutput();

    // Some time consuming work
    await Task.Delay(50000);

    return Ok(result);
}
```

I think fire and forget is not good idea.

I want to get status if the process is still running or completed on client side.

How can I implement this kind(job) pattern. Is there any example , resource I can follow. Please share some idea or available resource.

I am new to .NET API's . Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: With that kind of controller action, the job will be complete when the HTTP response is received.

Comment: From this code in your question, client side will stuck until the backend return the value... If you want the backend to actively sends data, I think you can use [SignlaR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

Comment: @XinranShen Thanks for quick response! Will look more in to that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that work synchronously, which is what you are showing. The "notification" is simply getting the OK response to your request. The problem with that is it will tie up a server thread and possibly lead to time outs.

A better way would be to refactor the code and conform to the [Asynchronous Request-Reply](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/async-request-reply) pattern. In this pattern, the client will continually poll some location on the server until the work is completed.

In this pattern there are several different ways to start the work in the background. Some common ones include

- queueing data to be consumed by a `BackgroundService`
- sending a message to another service
- using a `BackgroundWorker`
- starting a Task (for simplicity this is the one I'll show)

First let's create a few types to convey status and a status response. I'll mock up your `PushOutputs` type as well.

```cs
public enum Status { Running, Finished, Error }

public record StatusResponse(Guid Guid, Status Status);

public class PushOutput
{
    public PushOutput(Guid guid)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Next, let's build a controller. The controller will have 3 endpoints

- one for accepting the request to create/compute a result (for convenience
  I'll use a local method executed as a background task)
- one for getting the completed result
- one for polling for the result when it is ready

I'm handwaving a bit on the implementation, not knowing if you're using a database, etc.

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class PushOutputsController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> TimeConsumingApi(object payload)
    {
        var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
        SaveGuidAndStatusSomewhere(guid, Status.Running);

        Task.Run(DoWork).ContinueWith(Done);

        // tell the client to poll a temporary URL
        return Accepted("https://server.com/pushoutputs/status/{guid}");

        void DoWork()
        {
            // long running work using payload
        }

        void Done(Task task)
        {
            SaveGuidAndStatusSomewhere(guid, task.Exception is not null ? Status.Error : Status.Finished);
        }

        void SaveGuidAndStatusSomewhere(Guid correlationId, Status status)
        {
            // e.g. to a database table
        }
    }

    [HttpGet("status/{guid}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetStatus(Guid guid)
    {
        var status = GetStatusFromSomewhere();

        Status GetStatusFromSomewhere()
        {
            // get status from somewhere (hard coded to Finished
            // here, but it would really be one of the 3 statuses
            return Status.Finished;
        }

        if (status == Status.Finished)
            // this will redirect to the Get() API
            return Redirect("https://server.com/pushoutputs/{guid}");

        // it's not ready yet, just let caller know to continue polling.
        // important to return the guid AND the status, so client knows
        // which one to poll for
        return Ok(new StatusResponse(guid, status));
    }

    [HttpGet("{guid}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetPushoutput(Guid guid)
    {
        // hardcoded, in reality you'd hit a database or something
        var po = new PushOutput(guid); 
        return Ok(po);
    }  
}
```

The way this works is

1. Client POSTs a request.
2. Server starts a task and begins the work.
3. Server sends a `202 Accepted` with a temporary location client can poll.
4. Client polls that location and gets `200 OK` until the work is done.
5. When work is done, server sets status to `Finished`.
6. Client polls one final time and gets `302 Redirected` to the finished result.

> NOTE: I am using the generated GUID as the ID of the result as well. In reality you'd need some way to lookup the new ID of the new object using the
> guid as a key.

Finally, if polling is not an option for you, SignalR would be a way to push the response instead of pulling. I'll leave that to you to explore.

Comment: Thank you very much. This very helpful and informative answer.